# If H is a group with odd order, how do I prove there is no nontrivial homomorphism f: D7 /to H

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that D7/Ker f is isomorphic to f(D7). Since |D7/ker f| must equal 1, 2, 7, or 14, I know that I can rule out 2 and 14 since it must divide the order of H which is odd.

I'm clueless on what to do for 7 though.

Comment: The kernel of a homomorphism $G \to H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. How many normal subgroups of $D_7$ do you know of?

Comment: I feel like I knew at some point, but all I can recall right now is that there is at most one, and it probably doesn't contain 7 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your generators of $D_7$ are $a$ and $b$, with
$$ a^7=e, \quad b^2 = e, \quad bab=a^{-1}. $$
Now, to make a group homomorphism to a group of order $7$. There is only one group of order $7$, $C_7$. Hence we need to send $a$ to a non-identity element, which we may as well call $\phi(a) = A$. Note that $A$ has order $7$.

Now, we need to do something with $b$. Since $b$ has even order, and $C_7$ has only one element of even order, we have to set $\phi(b)=e$. Now look at what happens to the relation $bab=a^{-1}$ under $\phi$.

Comment: $\phi(bab) = A^6$, but $\phi(b)\phi(a)\phi(b) = A$, making it not a homomorphism? Is this the contradiction?

Comment: Yes: you can't make something that satisfies the homomorphism property because $\phi(e) = \phi(baba) = \phi(b)\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a) = A^2 \neq e$. Hence the assumption that $\phi(a) \neq e$ had to be wrong, and the homomorphism has to be trivial.

Comment: Awesome! Quick question though, how do we know that the only group of order 7 is C7? And also, was my reasoning for 2 and 14 ok?

Comment: Both come from Lagrange's theorem and Cauchy's theorem: there must be an element of order $7$ in a group of order $7$ (or similarly for any prime), so it must be cyclic. For $2$ and $14$, you look at the order of the image of $D_7$, which is a subgroup of $H$, so its order divides the order of $H$. As you note, this can't happen for even-size images if $|H|$ is odd.